# PrintService in java wont work once hosted in heroku

Tags: java, heroku, printing

I have this printService snippet written :

```
public class MainTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.SERVICE_FORMATTED.PRINTABLE;
        //PrintService defPrnSrvc = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
        PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();

        PrintService[] services = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null);
        System.out.println("my printer found: " + services.length);
        // this step is necessary because I have several printers configured
        for (int i = 0; i < services.length; i++) {
            String svcName = services[i].toString();
            //
        }
    }
}
```

But when I host it in heroku, it does not show any printer, I know the reason, that the printer service looks in your local system, thus it wont work on heroku, but is there a workaround to this, like if I send some details from my local, like IP address or Mac address of my computer then it can search the printers in that computer?

Is there a way how to pass parameters to printservice class to get the printers of a particular computer? Or does it always looks in localhost.

Comment: No, code running on Heroku (or any other remote server) can't enumerate printers installed on your local machine.

Comment: The print service is dependent on the available printer system of the OS and it's available drivers

Answer (score 0):

Interesting. I don't think Heroku has plugins for connecting to local devices in a given location, but here's a couple of ideas:

- If your printer is cloud enabled, you can check the manufacturer docs of the printer to see whether there's a way to connect remotely. Probably involves flipping a setting on the printer(s) itself too.
- Have you looked into Google's project for this, and does it work for your use case? https://www.google.com/cloudprint/#printers
- This is the long way around, but you could probably hook up a Raspberry Pi to the printer, and use it to host an API endpoint so the pi can receive document data and any instructions you need, then pass it to the local printer via the local connection.

Hope this helps!